# Comparing 2 tables, and getting rows where the count is same

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1

```
ID   class
1    A
2    A
3    B
4    C
```

Table2

```
ID   class
1    A
3    B
4    C
```

Hi, is there an easy way to compare the count(class) of each table, and if the 2 tables have the same count for that class, return the ID and class.

Want to get the following results:

```
ID  class
3   B
4   C
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Class
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT Class, COUNT(*) AS NumberOf
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Class
) x1 ON t1.Class = x1.Class
JOIN
(
    SELECT Class, COUNT(*) AS NumberOf
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY Class
) x2 ON x1.Class=x2.Class AND x1.NumberOf = x2.NumberOf
```

Edited as I misunderstood originally! I've arbitrarily just returned the IDs from Table1 where the number of a given class matches in both tables

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    tbl1.class
FROM
    (SELECT class, count(1) as cnt FROM table1 GROUP BY class) tbl1,
JOIN (SELECT class, count(1) as cnt FROM table2 GROUP BY class) tbl2 ON tbl1.class=tbl2.class

WHERE 
    tbl1.cnt=tbl2.cnt
```

You won't get the IDs, because in case there are more IDs for B or C classes, the Database engine won't know which one to pick. You'd have to write a more complex query once you know what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CLASS, ID
  FROM TABLE1
  WHERE CLASS IN
    (SELECT CLASS FROM
      (SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT CLASS, COUNT(*) AS class_count
           FROM table1
           GROUP BY CLASS) T1
      INNER JOIN
        (SELECT CLASS, COUNT(*) AS class_count
           FROM table2
           GROUP BY CLASS) T2
        USING (CLASS, CLASS_COUNT)));
```

This returns the ID and CLASS from TABLE1 and works for the test data provided.  Not guaranteed to work for all possible combinations of data.  Use at your own risk.  Not for use in medical equipment, air traffic control systems, or other applications involving risk of serious injury, death, or liability.  Your mileage may vary.  Use by children under the age of 16 should be monitored by a responsible adult.  Do not use in the presence of strong magnetic fields, high winds, or rains of frogs or other small amphibians.  Use in the presence of large amphibians or carnivorous reptiles is discouraged.  Not tested on animals - you'll be the first!

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using the new clause INTERSECT.

For more details about this new clause please have a look at this post:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/03/sql-server-2005-difference-between-intersect-and-inner-join-intersect-vs-inner-join/